# Double circle button hover

Tags: jquery, button, hover, overlay

I made a button compose by two circle like this:

```js
$('.circle').mouseover(function(){
   $('.overlay').animate({opacity:0.7,}, 200);
  }); 
$('.circle').mouseout(function(){
 $('.overlay').animate({opacity:0}, 100);
});
```

```css
.overlay{
 position:absolute;
 background:black;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 opacity:0;
}
 


.circle{
 position:absolute;
 width:30px;
 height:30px;
 border:1px dashed #fc7945;
 border-radius:50px;
 cursor:pointer;
 z-index:99;
}

.circle-in{
 width:20px;
 height:20px;
 margin-top:2px;
 background:none;
 margin-left:2px;
 border:3px solid #fc7945;
 border-radius:50px;
 cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overlay"></div> 

<a><div class="circle">
         <div class="circle-in"></div>
        </div></a>
```

and i want that when i hover on it the overlay appear, so my problem is that when i hover on it there is a breakpoint between the first and the second circle and that make the overlay disappear and appear how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**`stop()`**](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) any currently-running animations:

```
$('.circle')
  .mouseover(function() {
    $('.overlay').stop().animate({  //add stop() here
      opacity: 0.7,
    }, 200);
  })
  .mouseout(function() {
    $('.overlay').stop().animate({  //and here
      opacity: 0
    }, 100);
  });
```

```js
$('.circle')
  .mouseover(function() {
    $('.overlay').stop().animate({
      opacity: 0.7,
    }, 200);
  })
  .mouseout(function() {
    $('.overlay').stop().animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, 100);
  });
```

```css
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}
.circle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px dashed #fc7945;
  border-radius: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 99;
}
.circle-in {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  background: none;
  margin-left: 2px;
  border: 3px solid #fc7945;
  border-radius: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overlay"></div>

<a>
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="circle-in"></div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not because of the space between the circles, but moving from the outer to the inner circle triggers a pointer event (mouseout, mousein), which causes the animations to start over.

You can prevent that by disabling those events on the inner circle completely by adding one line of CSS to the inner circle. The rest of the code can remain unchanged, and there is little change of side effects, since you don't need work-arounds for the animation. IE only supports this since [version 11](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events), though.

```
pointer-events: none;
```

```js
$('.circle').mouseover(function(){
   $('.overlay').animate({opacity:0.7,}, 200);
  }); 
$('.circle').mouseout(function(){
 $('.overlay').animate({opacity:0}, 100);
});
```

```css
.overlay{
 position:absolute;
 background:black;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 opacity:0;
}
 


.circle{
 position:absolute;
 width:30px;
 height:30px;
 border:1px dashed #fc7945;
 border-radius:50px;
 cursor:pointer;
 z-index:99;
}

.circle-in{
 width:20px;
 height:20px;
 margin-top:2px;
 background:none;
 margin-left:2px;
 border:3px solid #fc7945;
 border-radius:50px;
 cursor:pointer;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overlay"></div> 

<a><div class="circle">
         <div class="circle-in"></div>
        </div></a>
```